# "numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge" on a very simple example

Tags: python, numpy, svd

I am doing the very simple task of taking the SVD of matrix 'm1203.raw.mat', a very sparse matrix containing only a handful of values, i.e.,

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){print $i}}' m1203.raw.mat | sort | uniq -c
```

returns

```
227510 0.0
   979 -1.0
  1070 1.0
    22 -2.0
    27 2.0
     1 -3.0
     2 -4.0
     3 4.0
     1 -7.0
     1 7.0
```

but the matrix is almost an MB in size (otherwise I'd attach it)

in any case, this simple task

```
import numpy

a = numpy.loadtxt('m1203.raw.mat')

s = [float(i) for i in range(-7,8)]

for r in a :
  for c in r :
    assert(c in s)

numpy.linalg.svd(a)
```

gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trial.py", line 4, in <module>
    numpy.linalg.svd(a)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1327, in svd
    u, s, vt = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 99, in _raise_linalgerror_svd_nonconvergence
    raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge")
numpy.linalg.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge
```

any idea?

Comment: That usually happens in the presence of NaNs. Make sure the matrix file does not have any garbage and that you've read it correctly.

Comment: Usually the presence of NaNs or infinite values will raise a ValueError

Comment: this is not the case, as the above awk command already demonstrates that the matrix consists only of the values in this set : [0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, -4, 4, -7, 7]

Comment: just another thing, I tried the same in R and got the same error with its svd method.  I then tried it in Matlab, and it worked.  This is strange because all three (Python, R and Matlab) rely on LAPACK for the SVD computation